# Android Studio is not showing ListView entries

Tags: android, listview

My android Studio is not showing the entries of ListView in the designing tab. I have a string array as the entries of the ListView but the designing tab only shows Items inside the ListView instead of my own string array. The interesting fact is, when i run it on emulator, it shows the string array and works fine....
Here is [The image of what the design tab is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vlTM.png) and
[The image of the app running in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLdA8.png)

Comment: I am not sure if the android studio preview is even supposed to do that. The preview pane is not an emulator, how should it know the values you want to present?

Comment: Extending on this even further, I wouldn't rely on the design tab but so much. It is known to be buggy and trying to create layouts using JUST the design view has been known to create a wreck of xml.

Comment: Then how does it show the text of a TextView or Image of an ImageView? @Nikola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android studio doesn't know what items you are going to dynamically put into the list view. So it puts there a few examples.

Comment: Then how does it show the text of a TextView or Image of an ImageView?

Comment: That is different. For the TextView you put the text into the xml so Android Studio can easily guess what text to show . For a list you have an adapter which can do anything so Android Studio cannot guess what to display (it only shows the layout).

Comment: Thank you.now i understood it :) @jbarat

Answer (score 0):

Use tools keyword in your list view for example:
tools:listitem="@layout/layout_name"
It helps you to get view of runtime display in design tab.

Comment: So the consider ListView in runtime?  
Then how does it show the text of a TextView or Image of an ImageView? instantly?